# iOS notification through FCM no sound when app in background

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a notification to an iOS app using Firebase Cloud Massaging. But I have problems making it play the notification sound on an iOS 16 device when the app is in background. Here is the payload I send for my notification

```
const message: Message = {
        apns: {
            headers: {
                "apns-priority": "10",
            },
            payload: {
                "aps": {
                    "alert" : {
                        "title" : "Rise and Shine",
                        "body" : "Time to wake up! Get up and move!"
                    },
                    contentAvailable: true,
                    sound: "default"
                }
            }
        },
        data: {
            value: '850',
        },
      // Get token from db
        token: await getFCMToken()
    }
```

In my iOS project I implemented MessagingDelegate and UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication
                        .LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        configureFCMPushNotification(application)

        return true
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
        if let token = token {
            sendTokenToBackend(token: token)
        }
    }
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

    func configureFCMPushNotification(_ application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { granted, error in
                print(granted)
                print(error)

            }
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        } else {
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("log")
        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("3")
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
    }
}
```

On my iOS16 device, when the app is in foreground and I send a notification all is well, the notification arrives and the default sound is played. But when the app is in background and I send a notification I don't get any sound for the notification.

I have enabled Push Notification and the required background modes (bg fetch, remote notification and bg processing)

I understand that willPresent is called only when app is in foreground. And since in that method I specify I want sound for notification it makes sense that when the app is in foreground it works.

But I couldn't find anything similar for when the app is in bg. I also double checked with a known working project and I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64516960/ios-handle-notifications-and-payload-when-app-is-in-background#:~:text=while%20sending%20a%20background%20push,if%20it's%20in%20the%20background

Comment: I tried what you suggested there. It helped a bit. Omitting the type header of background(which made the notification not show at all) that made the notification sound play while the app in background. However, when I close the screen, there is still no sound

Comment: try removing the sound: "default" from your payload.

Comment: Well without that no sound is played at all

Comment: @AdrianPascu did you try to change default sound to any custom sound ?? let me know

Answer (score -1):

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification) on "content-available": *The background notification flag. To perform a silent background update, specify the value 1 and don’t include the alert, badge, or sound keys in your payload. See Pushing background updates to your App.*

This suggests that the content-available does not play along nicely with alert/badge/sound and should be omitted from payloads which should notify the user.