# How to show communication notifications in Swift UI in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am making a chat app in SwiftUI and firebase, and I would like to show notifications when a user receives a new message.
I was able to send push notifications with cloud messaging in firebase, but these weren't send automatically.

Now I'd like to send communication notifications automatically when a user receives a message.
I wasn't able to find any tutorials for communication notifications in the background in swift and firebase.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging

@main
struct SimplePhoneApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Main()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) async -> UIBackgroundFetchResult {
        return .noData
    }
}


extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification) async -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        print(userInfo)
        return [[.alert, .sound]]
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        print(userInfo)
    }
    
    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) async -> UIBackgroundFetchResult {
//      Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        
        print(userInfo)
        
        return UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

      let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(
        name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
        object: nil,
        userInfo: dataDict
      )
    }
}
```

This is working code for sending a communication notification:

```
func scheduleCustomNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "New Message"
    content.body = "You have a new message from John Doe."
    
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false) // Schedule notification to appear after 5 seconds
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error scheduling notification: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Custom notification scheduled successfully.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, based on what you have provided, you seem to be creating an [**UIKit**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit) app, not [**SwiftUI**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I am making an app with SwiftUI, the code above is just a part of my app code, I've edited the code in my question

Comment: You will need to investigate [cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd) to send a notification from the server

Comment: @Paulw11 but that's for node.js and python?

Comment: Yes. You are going to need to run that code in the cloud and have it send the notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scheduleCustomNotification() triggers a local notification, its not related to firebase in anyway .

You need to check :

- if you added your .p12 or p8 file into firebase console.
- You can send remote notification from the firebase console to see what you receive (Firebase handles the building of your notification).
- check your project background modes (remote notification activated).

maybe it can help:
[iOS Handle notifications and payload when app is in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64516960/ios-handle-notifications-and-payload-when-app-is-in-background)

https://www.kodeco.com/20201639-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-ios-push-notifications

Comment: I know that, but I was an already able to post a test notification in the firebase console. But this scheduleCustomNotification was just to test local notifications, because I thought I could use this whenever I received a message from Firestore, but then I don't know how to run that in the background
I did all the stuff you said in your response

Comment: I have done all the stuff from the second link, but that only allows me to publish test notifications

Comment: You cannot use scheduleCustomNotification() in the background. its a a foreground service only.
What you can do is using a firebase cloud function to send push notification when something has changed in the you're firestorm table.

To be received and displayed notifications need to be a "push notification" sent through apns. That's why tests notifications from the console work. They use the apns service.

Comment: I can only do that with node.js in cloud functions then?

Comment: https://matthomrich.medium.com/ios-push-notifications-through-firebase-cloud-functions-a518fac58e13

To trigger a remote notification in background - using firebase data change - yes